# SVN error : Write-lock stolen

Tags: svn, locking

This is how I encounter the problem,

I opened my working copy, make an update which takes huge amount of time (I interrupted it), then clean the locks, then I got this error:

> Write lock stolen

I really don't know what is going here, I read a few things about corrupted file system, but I don't think this is the case (as I can access the hardrive without troubleshooting)...

How to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be seeing this (http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3430) issue?

Answer (score 12):

for short:  "svn cleanup"  may solve your problem.

I think some files in your SVN local folder was locked.

```
$ cd <your_folder>
$ svn up
```

Then if you got :

```
...
M       db/schema.rb
M       Gemfile.lock
    S   files            
?       files/templates.zip
...
```

the "S files" means there are conflicts in this folder/file.   so we need to remove the conflict files, then run "svn cleanup" :

```
$ rm files -rf
$ svn cleanup
$ svn up
...
A    files
...
Updated to revision 1881.
```

now svn is OK.